# How to generate sequence like

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+---+------------+
| V | output     |
+---+------------+
| y |          1 |
| y |          2 |
| y |          3 |
| N |          0 |
| y |          1 |
| y |          2 |
| N |          0 |
| N |          1 |
+---+------------+
```

Comment: You cannot.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, you need a column that specifies the ordering in order to get the result that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample output is some how a little bit complex,

I preferred to use a [SQL recursive query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) for the solution of your problem
Of course I assume that the id column is starting from 1 and goes continuosly without any gap. In a more complex case, the row_number() function should be added besides id field and join should be setup on rownumbers

I hope it helps,

```
--create table bool(id int identity(1,1), bool char(1))
--insert into bool values ('Y'),('N'),('Y'),('Y'),('Y'),('N'),('Y'),('N'),('N'),('Y'),('Y'),('Y'),('Y'),('Y'),('N'),('Y'),('Y')

;with cte as (
    select id, bool curr, bool pre, 1 output from bool where id = 1
    union all
    select 
        bool.id, bool.bool curr, cte.curr, 
        case when bool.bool = cte.curr then cte.output + 1 else case when bool.bool = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end end
    from cte
    inner join bool on bool.id = cte.id + 1
)
select * from cte
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let me assume that you have a column (say, `id`) that has the ordering information.  Then, you want to identify groups of "Y"s and "N"s that appear together and then enumerate them.

You can do this using a difference of row numbers trick:

```
select t.v,
       row_number() over (partition by v, seqnum_id - seqnum_vid order by id) as output
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum_id,
             row_number() over (partition v by order by id) as seqnum_vid
      from t
     ) t;
```

Explaining how this works is usually tricky.  I recommend that you run the subquery to see what the sequence numbers look like and why the difference is constant for the groups you want to identify.